# How to extend a Scala class with functionality without modifying this particular class?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

Let's say I want to encapsulate functionality of a class, meaning I want to introduce a proxy between clients and this particular class. For example, Play's `Result` class has the following method:

```
  /**
   * Adds headers to this result.
   *
   * For example:
   * {{{
   * Ok("Hello world").withHeaders(ETAG -> "0")
   * }}}
   *
   * @param headers the headers to add to this result.
   * @return the new result
   */
  def withHeaders(headers: (String, String)*): Result = {
    copy(header = header.copy(headers = header.headers ++ headers))
  }
```

Let's assume that I don't want to use this method directly, but instead I want to use a proxy. So instead of calling `Redirect(controllers.app.routes.Application.index).withHeaders(<XYZ>)` I want to call my own method which subsequently calls `.withHeaders(<XYZ>)`:

`Redirect(controllers.app.routes.Application.index).customWithHeaders(<XYZ>)`

How can this be implemented? Can this be done by implementing a trait which will be extended by controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import play.api.mvc.Result

implicit class ResultUtils (result: Result) {
    def withCustomHeaders(pairs: (String, String)*): Result = result.withHeaders(pairs: _*)
}
```

with ResultUtils in scope, you can now do `Redirect(something).withCustomHeaders`

**Package Object**

```
package object common {
    implicit class ResultUtils (result: Result) {
      def withCustomHeaders(pairs: (String, String)*): Result = result.withHeaders(pairs: _*)
    }
}

import common._ //import common and get this class in scope
```

**Trait**

```
trait Implicits {
  implicit class ResultUtils (result: Result) {
      def withCustomHeaders(pairs: (String, String)*): Result = result.withHeaders(pairs: _*)
    }
}

class ApplicationController @Inject() () extends Controller extends Something with Implicits {
  def fooAction = Action { Ok("bar").withCustomHeaders("foo" -> "bar") }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! Is there a nice and easy way to encapsulate this `implicit class` to make it more reusable? I have multiple controllers where I want to use this. I guess I should wrap it in a trait, right?

Comment: @JohnDoe yes. put this inside package object and import the package anywhere you like

Comment: @JohnDoe edited the answer with `package object solution`